# scala ArrayBuffer remove all elements with a predicat

Tags: scala, arraybuffer

Scala is very elegant in filtering immutable sequences:

```
var l = List(1,2,3,4,5,6)
l = l.filter(_%2==1)
```

But how do I do this with a mutable collections like ArrayBuffer?
All I found is the removal of single elements or slices, or remove elements from another sequence, but nothing that removes elements given by a predicate.

Edit:
I was hoping to find something similar tho this:

```
trait Removable[A] extends Buffer[A]{ 
  def removeIf(p: A => Boolean){
    var it1 = 0
    var it2 = 0

    while(it2 < length){
      if( p( this(it2) ) ){
        it2 += 1;
      } 
      else {
        this(it1) = this(it2)
        it1 += 1;
        it2 += 1;
      }
    }

    trimEnd(it2-it1)
  }
}
```

this filters in linear time and can be mixed into any Buffer, but only ArrayBuffer makes sense, on ListBuffers it would be slow, because indexing does take linear time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that it's more efficient to filter by building a new buffer, so you would normally just use `filter` and use its result. Otherwise you can write your own in-place filter method:

```
def filterInPlace[A](b: collection.mutable.Buffer[A])(fun: A => Boolean): Unit = {
  var sz = b.size
  var i = 0; while(i < sz) {
    if (fun(b(i))) {
      i += 1
    } else {
      sz -= 1
      b.remove(i)
    }
  }
}

val b = collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer((1 to 6): _ *)
filterInPlace(b)(_ % 2 == 1)
println(b)
```

Comment: Your `filterInPlace` is slow, because `b.remove(i)` is an O(n) method.

Answer (score 2):

You do it the same with `ArrayBuffer`. All collection classes have the same methods available.

Answer (score 1):

There has been discussion about having a set of methods that work by performing mutation, but coming up with a good, generic set is surprisingly hard, and, on the other hand, there just hasn't been enough demand for it.

Comment: I guess I'm not demanding loudly enough, or there are too few of me.

Comment: @Rex I'm just waiting for you to implement them and submit to Scala Incubator. :-) Realistically, EPFL people has limited resources, and some important stuff gets left out. See the fate of `-save`, for example.

Comment: I practically offered to write them myself in the scala-debate thread I started a few months back.  Maybe you're right and there's so little demand that it's not even worth asking someone else to implement it.

Comment: @Rex I have worked with open source before, so I can give you their probable perspective on it. Suggestions are infinite and offers of help abound. However, very few get in on to the other side, and any code added to a codebase is an additional burden on _working_ on that code base. So even a full implementation is looked at with wariness, but, yet, it is the only effective way of getting something in: doing all the work _before_ offering it.

Comment: Indeed.  Unfortunately, I only have enough time to work on things that have a good chance of being used.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, but only with clone(), thus still making a new ArrayBuffer :-)

```
scala> import collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
import collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

scala> val buf = ArrayBuffer(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
buf: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Int] = ArrayBuffer(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)

scala> buf.clone foreach { x => if (x > 4) buf -= x }

scala> buf
res1: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Int] = ArrayBuffer(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

But better way would be to make a new array of only those elements, which you want to remove (thus not copying the whole buffer) and then remove them:

```
scala> val buf = ArrayBuffer(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
buf: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Int] = ArrayBuffer(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)

scala> buf filter { _ > 4 } foreach { buf -= _ }

scala> buf
res3: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Int] = ArrayBuffer(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Comment: yes your solution would work, but it would be in time O(n^2), because each remove is a search and a rearrangement of the Buffer. I was looking for something that works in O(n). But I think I need to do it myself.

Comment: I think here in mutable case it will never be O(N). But if you do classic immutable filter, then you have it in O(N) :-).

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this

```
import scala.collection.mutable

trait BufferUtils {
    import BufferUtils._
    implicit def extendMutableBuffer[T](org: mutable.Buffer[T]): ExtendedBuffer[T] = new ExtendedBuffer(org)
}

object BufferUtils extends BufferUtils {

    implicit class ExtendedBuffer[T](val org: mutable.Buffer[T]) extends AnyVal {
        def removeIf(pred: (T) => Boolean): Unit = {
            // target holds the index we want to move the next element to
            var target = 0

            for (i <- org.indices;
                 elem = org(i)
                 if !pred(elem)) {

                org(target) = elem
                target += 1
            }

            org.remove(target, org.size - target)
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Often `withFilter` is good enough, especially if the Buffer is converted to an immutable structure in the end. True, it doesn't really remove the elements, but at least it doesn't create a new ArrayBuffer object.