# ArrayBuffer copy all fields of this to another ArrayBuffer for first N entries

Tags: scala

This works:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
case class Z (a1:String, b1:String, ts1: Integer)

var d = new ArrayBuffer[Z]()  // empty buffer is created
d = ArrayBuffer(Z("Mark", "Hamlin", 2), Z("Kumar", "XYZ", 3), Z("Tom", "Poolsoft", 4)) 

//val g = d1.map(x => (x.a1, x.b1, x.ts1)) 
var Z1 = new ArrayBuffer[Z]()
for (x <- d) {
  Z1 += Z(x.a1, x.b1, x.ts1) 
}
println(Z1)
```

How can I clone an entry of Z in the loop without having to specify all the field name of case class Z? `Z(x.a1, x.b1, x.ts1)` Cannot see that. There is a reason why I want to do it individually.

copyToArray and clone seem no go here. I would be happy if I could use a size as well, but am interested in the prime question.

I looked at this [scala ArrayBuffer remove all elements with a predicat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5546205/scala-arraybuffer-remove-all-elements-with-a-predicat) ,but I have no filter I can use. I need, say, first N to be copied.

Comment: Why not just `Z1 += x`? Also, one may wonder why you even need mutability and array buffers at all, but I would leave such considerations outside of the question.

Comment: _"copyToArray and clone seem no go here"_ why?

Comment: I could not get it to work @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez. Please post an improvement.

Comment: Again, I am pretty sure all this is pretty pointless but anyways: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/be51vnZyQ6eMLesMgburNw/5

Comment: No its not. Long story short I am developing some code for data engineers. We have kafka, sp str streaming, but i am simulating that part with an ArrayBuffer that has writes to it it, inserts, and microbatch reads from it. As this is upfront work and not the core problem i am using this simulation which is single writer single reader and improving my scala knowledge. I formulated the question a little odd as it was to do the first N as in the title. But I think I have it. @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez

Comment: The three copy methods that I shared with you allow you to get the first N elements. Also, if you want to simulate a Queue, why not just a queue?!

Comment: I did look at the queue but somehow got to arraybuffer.

Comment: In the initial thought and maybe still it was the result of microbatches in a db and fifo did not apply. I am thinking on that but for the first part the queue could have been used in a slightly different setup. @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez looks good, should have been an / the answer. Learnsome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering "How can I clone an entry of Z in the loop without having to specify all the field name of case class Z?":

If you really want to create a new instance of each `Z`, you could do:

```
for (x <- d) {
  Z1 += x.copy()
}
```

But: most certainly, you do not need to do that. The `Z`-objects in your ArrayBuffer are immutable, so there is no reason to copy them (no one can modify them...). Instead, you could just add the same instances to your copied buffer:

```
for (x <- d) {
  Z1 += x
}
```

Since each `x` is immutable, there should not be a difference (but the second option saves the garbage collector some work because less objects get allocated).

Comment: I also want the first N.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use vars, mutable collections and arrays. That's not how you write code in scala. Also avoid procedural loops.

```
val d = Seq(Z("Mark", "Hamlin", 2), Z("Kumar", "XYZ", 3), Z("Tom", "Poolsoft", 4)) 
val d1 = d.take(2) // copies first two elements from d to d1
val d2 = d.drop(2) // removes first two elements from d and assigns the rest to d2

// or do both take and drop at once:
val (d1, d2) = d.splitAt(2)
```